# Cannot convert value of type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" to type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server"

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell, smo

I'm trying to use SMO to restore a database via Powershell, however when I try to define and use a server object it gives me the following error:

```
Cannot convert argument "srv", with value: "[MJNHNX4]", for "SqlRestore" to type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server": "Cannot convert the "[MJNHNX4]" value of type 
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" to type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server"."
At line:38 char:1
+ $smoRestore.SqlRestore($server)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Here is my code in full (there's not a lot to it):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null

#clear screen
cls

#get backup file
$backupFile = "D:\databases\Perfmon.bak"
$servername = "MJNHNX4" 
$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($servername)
$backupDevice = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceItem") ($backupFile, "File")
$smoRestore = new-object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore")

#settings for restore
$smoRestore.NoRecovery = $false;
$smoRestore.ReplaceDatabase = $true;
$smoRestore.Action = "Database"

#show every 10% progress
$smoRestore.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;

$smoRestore.Devices.Add($backupDevice)

#read db name from the backup file's backup header
$smoRestoreDetails = $smoRestore.ReadBackupHeader($server)

#display database name
"Database Name from Backup Header : " + $smoRestoreDetails.Rows[0]["DatabaseName"]

$smoRestore.Database = $smoRestoreDetails.Rows[0]["DatabaseName"]

#restore
$smoRestore.SqlRestore($server)

"Done"
```

The error occurs regardless of what I try to pass to Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server and I'm really not sure why it would be giving me that particular error.  I've read through the TechNet articles on the [Server Constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms193710.aspx) and I really have no idea what's going on there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After some further testing and reading about the SMO syntax, it looks like I don't need to define the $server as a new object. Instead, just passing the name of the server to $server works fine.